# css @font-face doesn't work in https in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

in the magento site we are working on we use the following code to set fonts

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'maitcbtr';
  src: url("../fonts/MAITCBTR.TTF");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'maitcbtr-ie';
  src: url("../fonts/maitcbtr.eot");
}
```

now it works fine when we access the test server however the font doesn't work when we load up the site using https, i have already tried adding the following to the .htaccess file

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

that doesn't work, i have loaded up the page in both ie and chrome using both http and https and both display the font just fine

what is it that i'm doing wrong

Comment: @MrLister by that do you mean using the full url to the font file? if so then yes

Comment: Yes. I see I had a typo, sorry.